# Is the badges machine broken?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

I see no new badges awarded since approximately 3.30 UTC.

There are not [Notable Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/27/notable-question), [Famous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/28/famous-question), [Yearling](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling), [Nice Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer) new badges since that time while, in general, these kind of badges are normally awarded every few minutes to someone.

Is the badges machine broken?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some backend shenanigans were in play.

Some internal services were not resolving correctly - they are now.

Thanks for reporting!

Comment: I see many new badges being awarded now. This was very fast, thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this also the cause of the recent addition of ~600 first posts to the FP review queue?

Comment: @Matt - probably.

Comment: It looks like the [Englightened badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/19/enlightened) machine is broken again.